# cannot run query from power bi to azure

Tags: azure-sql-database, powerbi

I am trying to connect to azure database from Power Bi. I can connect to the database using Managment studio and I can connect using power bi if I do not specify the database name.

If I put the database name (needed when I want to run a query), PowerBI not not connecting and it's telling me that the IP address is not registered (I have added the IP address on the azure firewall, which is proved by the fact I can perfectly connect and import tables if I just put the server name).

Answer (score 2):

step 1 clean the stored credentials in the power bi -file>option and setting> data source setting> find your azure server and delete/clear permission

and then try to login to your azure sql

Comment: it worked! Fantastic! I had asked several colleagues that work with PowerBI and nobody knew the answer. Thank you!

Comment: Hey I glad that you find it useful, please vote it up